# jquery image define area polygon

Tags: jquery, image, polygon, tagging

I am using Jquery image annotate library (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-image-annotate/)
to apply tags to an image.
It allows us to add tags by creating a small rectangular box that can be dragged and placed on an area in the image and then tagged. Works well.
But, my requirement is to click on the image directly and define points which should be drawn as a polygon or a rectangle. How can i use jquery to do this?
I have seen this in one of the examples in google maps edit tool.We can click on the map and define the points and when double-clicked it completes the shape and opens the edit box.

Please let me know how do we achieve this.

Thanks
Vish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the [`<map>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)?

Update: Well, it sounds like what you want is to draw on top of an image. You would have to use canvas which doesn't work for IE. If you already have the coordinates, you could check out either of these options:

- [jQuery maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/)
- [mapper.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/) (non-jQuery)

Comment: Yes looked into the HTML map tag. But not sure how to directly mark an area on an image by defining points to create a polygon and tag it.